# Make an element have priority flow so that it doesn't wrap around other elements?

Tags: html, css, web

I have 3 elements on a page. [1 2 3]. All 3 have dynamic widths and I would like the middle element to stay in the middle and not be wrapped around. So when the left or right elements start to overflow, they will be pushed down and not the middle element.

I'm not sure how to actually do this. I've tried it with flex ordering, but that actually changes the flow of the document. I was also thinking of having element 1 offset into element's 2 position, and element 2 into element's 1 position, but once element 2 gets pushed down, it would look weird.

In case of any confusion, I'm basically trying to get the flow [1 2 3] with the visual of [2 1 3] so that the center element doesn't get pushed out.

Answer (score 0):

*I'M trying understand your problem*, so i will answer you according to what i understood!
you can put all elements in a father div and style it in CSS with `position: relative;` and put all elements inside this father div then these all "sons" elements take a css style `position: absolute`, and take your control on them by `top, right, left`

you can also using bootstrap or any framework like it or yet doing this in pure CSS and JS.

I hope that i understood what you exactly want and it helped you.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got to that understanding. The usual flow of the DOM is left to right (or right to left if you're using flex functionality) in terms of having content as inline or inline-blocks. If your page becomes big enough only to hold the first two elements, then the third elements will be wrapped (meaning it will be pushed down to a new line of content). I'm trying to make it so that when that happens, it only affects elements on the right and left, but doesn't affect the center/middle element.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it using floats. Set up dom as the normal flow of elements, so that the middle element will be first in the flow, the left element second, and the right element third. Float left the second element.